# HTML5 Geolocation script works in Chrome but not Safari or any iOS6 browser

Tags: jquery, html, ios6, geolocation, handlebars.js

My jquery script runs fine in Chrome, but has problems in latest version of Safari and all browsers on iOS6. The user gets prompted for permission to use geolcation in Safari, but then the rest of the code won't execute.

I'm aware that iOS6 has problems with Geolocation, but not sure if that's what's wrong here. Any advice deeply appreciated.

```
jQuery(window).ready(function(){  
  $('#circleG')
    .hide()  // hide spinner initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
            jQuery(window).load(initiate_geolocation);  
        });  
        function initiate_geolocation() {  
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors);  
        }  
        function handle_errors(error)  
        {  
            switch(error.code)  
            {  
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: 
                break;  
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:  
                break;  
                case error.TIMEOUT: 
                break;  
                default: 
                break;  
            }  
        }  


    function handle_geolocation_query(position){
   $.getJSON(BASE+'/yelphome', { latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude }, function(data) {

   var template = Handlebars.compile($('#template').html());

  $('div.adam').append( template(data.businesses));
 });
}
```

Comment: who cares about ios6? its probably gonna geolocate you somewhere in the australian wilderness anyway...lol.

Comment: Did you remember the API Key in the script src?

Comment: yes, the script brings back results and outputs them fine in Chrome. for some reason, Safari has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The W3C Standard is as follows.  I have used it successfully on many projects.

```
if(navigator.geolocation != undefined) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude,
        lng = position.coords.longitute;

        // DO STUFF HERE
    });
};
```

The `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` function is what actually prompts the user to provide their location and subsequently returns their location information.

I've tested this on Android, iOS, Windows, and OSX successfully.

I think you will find something like this will work just fine:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    if(navigator.geolocation != undefined) {    
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var lat = position.coords.latitude,
            lng = position.coords.longitute;

            // DO STUFF HERE
        }, function(error){
            switch(error.code)  
            {  
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: 
                break;  
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:  
                break;  
                case error.TIMEOUT: 
                break;  
                default: 
                break;  
            }  
        });
    };
})
```